# FadesOut the picture that is already there and FadeIn another Picture

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the image to fade in and after it fades out the image has changed to another one. If you look further down the code you can see that I have 3 functions that help me change images with one click of a button. However the animation fadeIn and fadeOut doesn't work. I tried my code but in reality nothing happens at all.

```js
var score = 0

function changeImage1() {
  document.getElementById("image1").src = "gold.png";
  document.getElementById("image2").src = "broken.png";
  document.getElementById("image3").src = "broken.png";
  score = 20
  console.log("You have recieved " + score)
}

function changeImage2() {
  document.getElementById("image1").src = "house.png";
  document.getElementById("image2").src = "iron.png";
  document.getElementById("image3").src = "iron.png";
  score = 50
  console.log(score)
}

function changeImage3() {
  document.getElementById("image1").src = "iron.png";
  document.getElementById("image2").src = "diamond.png";
  document.getElementById("image3").src = "gold.png";
  score = 0
  console.log(score)
}

var time = 10;
```

```html
<center>
  <h1>Win or Lose your Life?</h1>
</center>
<img alt="" src="pickaxe.png" style="height: 200px; width: 200px" id="image1" />
<button onClick="fadeOut()"><img src="button.png" id="button1" onclick="changeImage1()"/></button>

<img alt="" src="iron.png" style="height: 200px; width: 250px" id="image2" />
<button onClick="fadeOut()"><img src="button.png" id="button2" onclick="changeImage2()"/></button>

<img alt="" src="Diamond.png" style="height: 200px; width: 200px" id="image3" />
<button onClick="fadeOut()"><img src="button.png" id="button3" onclick="changeImage3()"/></button>
```

Comment: `However the animation fadeIn and fadeOut doesn't` because you haven't defined those functions...?

Comment: Well it's mosly because of the fact that I didn't work no matter what I do

Comment: I see no jQuery in this question.  but if you are wanting to fade in / out, then you probably need 2 images instead of just changing the source of one.  Also the `center` tag is obsolete and shouldn't be used

Comment: I tried that but in the end, all it did was just toggle the previous image

Comment: *I tried* - for future reference, it can help it include what you tried.  I could be something simple such as using the wrong selector or not using `this` and relative DOM navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) fadeOut() which allows for a callback when the fadeOut has completed.

Below is an example.  This has the issue that the second image takes time to load when set via "src=" so it fades in the old image before changing it.  This is terrible UX.

Better, as noted in the comments is to have 2 images as they'll load when the page loads (second snippet).

Example using `src=`

```js
var img1 = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg";
var img2 = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg";

$("button").click(function() { 
    $(this).find("img").fadeOut(function() { this.src = img2; $(this).fadeIn(); })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
click the image<br/>
<button class='btn'><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg"></button>
```

Example using two images

```js
$("button>img").click(function() { 
    $(this).fadeOut(function() { 
        // only 1, so siblings is ok
        $(this).siblings().fadeIn()
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
click the image<br/>
<button class='btn'>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxthA.jpg">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg" style='display:none;'>
</button>
```